# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add' (Django nested serializer)

Tags: django

I'm trying to update object but

```
if main_photos_data.get('id', None):
            MainPhoto.objects.filter(id=main_photos_data.get(
                'id')).update(**main_photos_data)
        else:
            id = instance.id
            project = Project.objects.get(id=id)
            new_main_photo = MainPhoto.objects.create(**main_photos_data)
            *project.main_photo.add(new_main_photo)* error in this line
```

getting this error:

```
  File "/home/askar/work/tasnif-backend/portfolio/serializers.py", line 143, in update
    project.main_photo.add(new_main_photo)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

I've tried:

```
project.main_photo = new_main_photo
```

But got this error:

```
TypeError at /portfolio/edit-project/1/
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use photo.set() instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
project.main_photo.id = new_main_photo.id
```